# How to Convert Uint8Array in Object.GetValue to byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, bytebuffer

I saved the Uint8Array value to Object. Then I bring it down to the DBHandler layer to make the image save by `byte[] = object.getvalue` of Uint8Array.

```
var o = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i].rawFile;
    console.log(file);
    
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
        var arrayBuffer = this.result;
        var view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        console.log(arrayBuffer);
        console.log(view);
        o.byte = view;
        o.name = file.name;
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

My image value like image:
[image]

Next is my DBhandler layer, and I don't know how to process to convert `Object.getValue ("byte")` to `byte[]`.

```
byte[] fileContent = new byte[(byte)objData.GetValue("byte")];

string filename = objData.GetValue("name").ToString();
```

When I debug, value is like image:
[image]

And It error like image: [image]

I tried `WebClient` to get `byte[]` according to Url with the same image then it output data as shown below.
[image]

I want to convert `Object.getValue` ("byte") to the same format as `WebClient` take Url image to `byte[]`. Hope everybody help me.

Comment: This question is confusing. Could you please elaborate or tell abstractly what you want to achive. Do you want to save and retrive data as byte array to and from?

Comment: @Sangeeth nandakumar I want convert value of "var view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);" to type byte[]. May output the same value of byte[] =>https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAAjy.png. Which I mentioned in the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert UInt8Array in little-endian format to byte[] array.
You can use this

```
byte[] output= input.SelectMany(BitConverter.GetBytes).ToArray();
```